# Smartphone badging system in remote places

Tags: android, ios, qr-code

How would you create an authentication system for workers in remote places?
Let's say i want to use the worker's smartphone to check when they enter or exit a building site in a not counterfeit way. But building sites can be in different places with some possibility of slow network. The app should be running on an Android or IOS Device.
Also NFC is not a good idea since the worker is going to use his own phone.
QR code would be fit but is it 100% counterfeit proof?

Comment: A static QR code is very easy to copy.  You could combine GPS location.  Location can be faked on on Android, I believe, and with a lot of difficulty on iOS but most people probably wouldn't.  A more secure solution would have a changing QR code from a tablet or similar onsite.  The QR code could then include a timestamp as well as the location code, making a copy of a given code useless.

Comment: The screenshot problem could be solved since the screenshot can be easily detected on ios and can be detected on android also. I did already think at a changing QR with timestamp

Comment: It's not a screenshot problem.  You can simply take a photo of the QR code and print it out or scan it from the screen of another phone.  Now you can check in to that site from anywhere.  You can also scan the QR code with some other app to get the data that is in the code and print your own copy.

Comment: Can you not just use location services to track the physical location of the device?

Comment: Yes sure, but the challenge is to do it as simple as possible, since i could use so many technologies but if i use nfc, locations and so on many workers could say "hey my phone doesn't have nfc" or "Oh my phone hasn't location" and so on.